# Creating space between fa icon and text

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a space between my fa icons and text but `fa-fw` isn't working and neither is`.i {margin-left: 10px;}`

Html:

```
<div class="logos1"><i class="fa fa-search">logos</i></div>
```

Comment: make the text outside the `i` tag

Comment: How?...........

Comment: why cant you do like that ? <div class="logos1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>logos</div>

Comment: Like This `<div class="logos1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span class="ml">logos<span></div>` Now You can give space to `.ml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    HTML
    <div class="logos1">
    <i class="fa fa-search">
    <span class="padding">logos</span>
    </i></div>

    CSS
    .padding{
     padding-left:10px;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing text between the i tag. This is not a good practice. You can achieve your goal using below code.

```css
i{
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="logos1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>logos</div>
```